# mount point does not exist

Tags: mount, chroot

In order to change forgotten root password, I performed these steps:

Boot from LiveUSB & run these commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
for d in dev sys run proc; do sudo mount --bind /$d /mnt/$d; done
```

Errors as below:

```
mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist
mount: mount point /mnt/sys does not exist
mount: mount point /mnt/run does not exist
mount: mount point /mnt/proc does not exist
```

Any hint?

Comment: After mounting /dev/sda1 on /mnt, what does an ls /mnt show you?

Comment: Possibly `/dev/sda1` is not a system root device?

Comment: @Adam  It shows lots of directories & files.

Comment: @Zanna  The /dev/sda1 is with the asterisk shown under "sudo fdisk -l"

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `ls /mnt` after the first command? The asterisk means it's the boot partition, which is definitely not the root partiton if you have a UEFI system

Comment: @nsr-ricer - When you say "lots of directories & files" is it too many to list in your initial post? (If so, consider using pastebin and posting a link here unless there's privacy concerns about what it lists).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you didn't hit the root device. Besides which, rather than setting up for a chroot, it is more expedient to simply do:

```
sudo mount --bind /mnt/etc/shadow /etc/shadow
sudo passwd # in the host system (!)
```

Comment: This is a good point, on many installs, /dev/sda1 will be /boot (not /). Always good to check you've mounted the correct partition first.